# Georgian London: they had Windows of course but ... Linux?

Tags: name-significance, sara-collins, the-confessions-of-frannie-langton

I'm reading (the Italian translation of) *The Confessions of Frannie Langton*, a novel set in Georgian London, and one of the preeminent characters is the housekeeper of George and Marguerite Benham, *Mrs Eustacia Linux*.

I'm curious if Sara Collins, the author of the novel, has given a rationale of this very particular (to my ear at least) name.

I searched online but eventual results are lost in the sea of links to miss Linux, in the understanding of what I'm missing in the Linux operating system with regard to other OS's...

Comment: For those who are interested, here is an [excerpt from the novel](https://www.penguin.co.uk/articles/2019/mar/the-confessions-of-frannie-langton-sara-collins-extract/) that mentions Mrs Linux. Fortunately, Sara Collins had the good taste not to call her [Hannah Montana Linux](https://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Operating-Systems/Linux-Distributions/Hannah-Montana-Linux-50229.shtml).

Comment: While it is not a direct statement by the author, [the country that most commonly uses that surname is Nigeria](https://forebears.io/surnames/linux). Do we know what race Eustacia is?

Comment: @SeanDuggan Mrs Linux ethnicity is never explicitly asserted in the first half of the book (i.e., what I've read) but she's definitely depicted as an English woman.

Comment: It makes sense to name a housekeeper Linux. After all she has root access to all the rooms ;-)

Comment: Related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_tax?wprov=sfla1 ?